# Is it possible to use ActiveModel with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, activemodel

I want to use ActiveModel in my Sinatra models to work with mongodb's Ruby driver. Is that a straight forward exercise or will there be problems?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to use. If u just need activerecord as your ORM, and create some models class like `class Data < ActiveRecord::Base`, the answer is yes.

Comment: @halfelf, ActiveRecord doesn't support Mongodb. You don't really need activerecord to be able to have ActiveRecord like models. That goodness comes from ActiveModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use MongoDB with an ORM you might want to consider using [Mongomapper](http://mongomapper.com/) or 
[Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html). They will offer you an Active Record like ORM.